# Java SQL Statement closing

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have simple Java program what listening for commands and then executing SQL queries. Program have following structure:

- Connect to database at launch
- Run SQL query to create TABLE IF NOT EXIST (`First Statement`)
- Listen for command `foo` and run `foo(cmd)` method

  - Execure SQL query inside this method (`Second Statement`)
  - This can be repeated multiple times
- Close connection when program killed

My question is how to handle `Statements`. Should I `create->execute->close` for every query?
Or should I create one `Statement` and use it multiple times (`statement.execute();`) until I stop application?

I am asking because my MySQL server is sometimes very lagged and I think its because I have too many unclosed statements or pool connections.

I am also sometimes getting error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.

Comment: You should create->execute->close for **every** query. Else you leak resources. And you should use a connection pool. And if you want even better performance, use `PreparedStatement` and you may need to tune your fetch size. This is not a topic that can be covered well on SO. There are multiple books on optimizing applications that use sql.

Comment: I dont need optimalization :) I just needed confirmation, that I should open->execute->close. I was not sure that Statements are not supposed to handle multiple queries.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should rarely use `Statement`; you almost always want `PreparedStatement`. Using `Statement` means you can't put any user input into the statement. If you try, i.e: `statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + userInput + "'");`, you've just written a security leak. What if the user sends as input: `"foo'; DROP TABLE users; EXECUTE SHELL 'rm -rf /'; --"?` - the only way out is to escape it, and `PreparedStatement` is how to do that.
2. connections are resources; they must be closed. So are statements (even preparedstatements), and so are resultsets. Each needs to be treated as a resource.

To work with resources, you write code like so:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)) {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?")) {
        ps.setString(1, username);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                // handle a row worth of results here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This construct ensures that no matter what happens (you return, break out, throw an exception - doesn't matter), once code moves out of the braces, the resource is properly disposed off. Failure to do this means the DB engine grows laggier over time and eventually your app crashes as the DB stops giving you more connections to let sit idle.

Comment: When exactly are resources "closed"? As I understand I do not need to explicitly call `.close()` on conn/statement

Comment: You need to explicitly call close, usually in a `finally` clause. The "try with resources" does this for you automatically, though, as in this answer.

Comment: @Baterka resources are closed whenever code flows out of the braces of the try {} statement here. It doesn't matter how. So, if you return in the middle of try (Connection con = ...) { /* code here */ return; /* more code here */ } – before it actually returns, the resource is closed first. Same goes if the code exits out of the block via exception, or just because it gets to the end. You don't need to call close yourself, it's taken care of for you.